# Solving a large sparse linear equation system

Tags: linear-algebra, math-software

Given $m=385$, I have a linear equation system over a field $\mathbb{F}_p$ with $p$ a small prime (could be 5,7,11, something like this) with the following properties:

1. There are $m^2$ variables.
2. Every variable appears in exactly 7 equation.
3. Every equation contains at most 3 variables.
4. The coefficient of the variables is always 1.
5. The free term in the equations are always 0, with one specific equation (an equation of the form $3x=1$ for a specific variable $x$).

I am currently using SAGE. It solved nicely smaller equation systems, but this one killed it, even when constructing the matrix as sparse ("Error allocating matrix"). The question is - should I simply try a better (and less convenient) sparse matrix handling package, or is there a better way to deal with such sparse systems of equations? (I can do a little programming myself if needed).

Comment: You will get more comprehensive replies for such questions @ scicomp.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have constant number of non-zero entries per row, your system is fit for [iterative methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov_subspace), namely in finite fields case: [Wiedemann's algorithm](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~kaltofen/bibliography/91/KaSa91.pdf). Check out [LinBox library](http://www.linalg.org/). As for convenience, AFAIK LinBox is included in SAGE.

Comment: Thank you! This seems very promising.

Comment: It seems there are two problems here. First, the algorithm is for square matrices, and mine isn't; second, the algorithm is not supposed to work well in small finite fields, which is exactly the case I'm dealing with.

Comment: (1) [Squarizer](http://www.linalg.org/linbox-html/class_lin_box_1_1_squarize.html) can handle rectangular matrices (2) IIRC LinBox supports small finite field through the field type [<Modular>](http://www.linalg.org/linbox-html/field_2modular_8h.html).

To find out more, you should post your problem to [LinBox users group](http://groups.google.com/group/linbox-use).